# Show nested list items on click

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having trouble with jQuery selectors and I can't find the problem with my code.

I have a series of nested lists:

```
<ol id="chaps">
  <li>Newton</li>
  <ul class="assignments">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Motion</li>
  <ul class="assignments">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</ol>
```

The `assignments` class has CSS set to `display:none` to hide the list.

The jQuery I've tried is:

```
$("#chaps > li").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("ul").find(".assignments").toggleClass("show");

});
```

...but it won't show the other options. I've gotten *all* of the `.assignments` classes to show with a similar script, but I'd like to keep it to the immediate sibling. Any help with the selector would be appreciated.

**Here's a [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/MwzJQx)**

Comment: You're better off placing the `ul` tags inside of the `li` tag. Then, the `ul` is a child of the clickable `li` parent.

Comment: Not just "better off" ... it is _required_.  An `<ol>` is _not allowed_ to have a `<ul>` as a direct child — no list may be a direct child of another list. The nested sub-list must be a child of an `<li>` within the enclosing list. See @PeterKA's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ul` elements cannot be child elements of `ol` elements but they can be child elements of `li` elements. And, just so you know, for next time you need to use it, `.closest( selector )` means:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

```js
$("#chaps > li").click(function() {
  $(this).find("ul.assignments").toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="chaps">
  <li>Newton
  <ul class="assignments hide">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Motion
  <ul class="assignments hide">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<li>Motion
  <ul class="assignments">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

This is the only way to nest list inside other list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a more generic widget that doesn't rely on a given HTML structure...

```
$.fn.toggleMenu = function(opt){

  opt = $.extend({
    hideClass:"hidden",
    selector:"ul",
    triggerEvents:"click"
  },opt)

  function _init(){
    $(this).each(_initEach);
  }
  function _initEach(){
    $(this).on(opt.triggerEvents,toggleVis);
  }
  function toggleVis(e){
    $(e.target)
      .children(opt.selector)
      .toggleClass(opt.hideClass);
  }
  _init();

}
$(".toggle_menu").toggleMenu({triggerEvents:"click mouseenter"});
```

This could be configured to accept any html structure.

[Try It!](https://jsbin.com/wuracusape/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from getting your code to work, it is always recommended to have a valid markup. ul/ol can not be direct child of another ul/ol. Your html is not valid and has the following errors as per W3 validator:

1.
Error: Element ul not allowed as child of element ol in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

From line 7, column 3; to line 7, column 26

on↩  ↩    <
Contexts in which element ul may be used:Where flow content is expected.Content model for element ol:Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.
2.
Error: Element ul not allowed as child of element ol in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

From line 12, column 3; to line 12, column 26

on↩  ↩    <
Contexts in which element ul may be used:Where flow content is expected.Content model for element ol:Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.